# Javascript slider not works

Tags: javascript, html, slider

```
var slideIndex = 0; 
showSlides();
function showSlides() 
{ 
    var i; 
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");  
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");  
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { 
        // initially set the display to  
        // none for every image. 
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    } 
    slideIndex++;  
    if (slideIndex > slides.length)  
    { 
        slideIndex = 1; 
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) { 
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className. 
                            replace(" active", ""); 
    } 
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; 
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active"; 
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);  
}
```

i try this for auto slider but it gives this error: 
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' or it tells that showSlides() is undefined

Comment: Why are you using showSlides(); in the second line? it doesn't identify the function before function implements.

Comment: @Pramuditha Javascript hoisting https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp will allow to use function anywhere within a block

Comment: I tried this code in fiddle and work fine for me. can provide more code or clarification..? how your execution going on....

Answer (score 0):

Please call function after define it.

```
var slideIndex = 0; 

function showSlides() 
{ 
    var i; 
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");  
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");  
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { 
        // initially set the display to  
        // none for every image. 
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    } 
    slideIndex++;  
    if (slideIndex > slides.length)  
    { 
        slideIndex = 1; 
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) { 
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className. 
                            replace(" active", ""); 
    } 
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; 
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active"; 
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);  
};
showSlides();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you following code is proper

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```